# Encog3 Neural Networks C# : What is the interface used to input multiple data points in encog3?

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

Here's the [pdf](http://www.heatonresearch.com/dload/ebook/IntroductionToEncogCS.pdf)! which I used to learn about encog implementation. I get how it works for one data point, my input has multiple data points.

- From my understanding, I think ILayer interface is used to define
  each layer, which I am not sure, Please clarify. And
- Which represents the data points in the interface?

Here is the ILayer interface :

```
public interface ILayer : ICloneable, IEncogPersistedObject 
{ 
 void AddNext(ILayer next); 
 void AddNext(ILayer next, SynapseType type); 
 void AddSynapse(ISynapse synapse); 
 INeuralData Compute(INeuralData pattern); 

 IActivationFunction ActivationFunction 
 { 
   get; 
   set; 
  } 

  int NeuronCount 
  { 
   get; 
   set; 
  } 

  IList<ISynapse> Next 
  { 
   get; 
  } 

  ICollection<ILayer> NextLayers 
  { 
    get; 
  }  

  double[] Threshold 
  { 
    get; 
    set; 
  } 

  int X 
  { 
    get; 
    set; 
  }  

  int Y 
  { 
    get; 
    set; 
  } 

  int ID 
  { 
    get; 
    set; 
  } 

  bool HasThreshold 
  {  
    get; 
  } 

  bool IsConnectedTo(ILayer layer); 
  void Process(INeuralData pattern); 
  INeuralData Recur(); 
  }
```

Comment: Hope this helps http://geekswithblogs.net/JoshReuben/archive/2011/02/04/c-neural-networks-with-encog.aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54575/An-Introduction-to-Encog-Neural-Networks-for-C

Comment: The example in this [site](http://geekswithblogs.net/JoshReuben/archive/2011/02/04/c-neural-networks-with-encog.aspx) is a sample application with one data point.

Answer (score 0):

ILayer interface is used to define my first layer i.e the input layer.

```
int NeuronCount
```

NeuronCount is what represents my number of data points. It was confusing initially, now clear.